# save images to folder from DeepFace.find()

Tags: python, pandas, face-detection, shutil, deepface

I have this code:

```
from deepface import DeepFace
image1 = "test.jpeg"
DeepFace.find(img_path = image1,   
              db_path = "faces",    
              enforce_detection = False)[0]
```

and the code outputs a table of output:

```
    identity    source_x    source_y    source_w    source_h    VGG-Face_cosine
0   faces/WhatsApp Image 2023-06-28 at 20.52.36.jpeg    395 541 664 664 0.157695
1   faces/1735674C-DDFD-491A-BDDA-291B8FF6DF79_1_1...   395 541 664 664 0.215283
2   faces/WhatsApp Image 2023-06-07 at 11.23.46.jpeg    395 541 664 664 0.273765
3   faces/WhatsApp Image 2023-06-21 at 18.38.12.jpeg    395 541 664 664 0.291210
4   faces/WhatsApp Image 2023-06-22 at 15.11.54.jpeg    395 541 664 664 0.297904
5   faces/WhatsApp Image 2023-06-13 at 18.49.11.jpeg    395 541 664 664 0.313946
```

instead of this output I want to save the similar images into a new folder

I have tried to convert it to a csv file but it haven't work

Comment: so it's a dataframe and it gives you the ROI of each match... please show an attempt to solve this yourself. [ask], [mre]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the code has a sample image and a set of images (inside the 'faces' directory) to compare with using deep face. You need to find and save similar images to the sample image in a new folder.

This is how we can modify your solution:
I'm using `shutil` library to copy files from the image path.

```py
import os
from shutil import copyfile
from deepface import DeepFace

image1 = "test.jpeg"
results = DeepFace.find(img_path = image1,   
              db_path = "faces",    
              enforce_detection = False)[0]

# creating output folder
similar_folder_name = 'similar_folder'
os.makedirs(similar_folder_name, exist_ok=True)

#  Iterating through matches to store in folder 
for index, row in results.iterrows():
    file_path = row["identity"]
    file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
    print(f"match found at: filename: {file_path}, cosine_similarity: {row['VGG-Face_cosine']}")
    new_file_path = os.path.join(similar_folder_name, file_name)
    # using shutil to copy image from path to new path
    copyfile(file_path, new_file_path)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it as shown below:

```
from deepface import DeepFace
import shutil

image1 = "test.jpeg"
dfs = DeepFace.find(img_path = image1,   
              db_path = "faces",    
              enforce_detection = False)[0]
for df in dfs:
   img_paths = df["identity"].values.tolist()
   for img_path in img_paths:
      shutil.copyfile(img_path, f"SOME_TARGET_FOLDER/{img_path}")
```